# Java -how can I store an array in switch case

Tags: java, arrays, function, recursion, switch-statement

I need to build code that first gets a 2d array and then prints it.
for this, I built a menu with a switch case.

when the user clicks 0, the user types the size of the array (the size is always n*n), and then the user types the values. then I need to create a function that uses this info to build a char array.(the values is hex base 0-F)

when the user clicks 1, the code needs to print the same 2d array.
I have a difficult time understanding how I can move the array from case 0.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment3 {

```
static Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int checker=1;
    int user_selction;
    
    
    do {
    
        user_selction=Menu();
        switch(user_selction) {
        case 0:
            Menu_0(user_selction);
            break;
        case 1:
            
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        case 4:
            checker=GoodBye(checker);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        
    }while(checker==1);

}
public static int Menu ()
{
    int menu_num;
    System.out.println("~ Photo Analyzed ~");
    System.out.println("0. Load Photo");
    System.out.println("1. Print Photo");
    System.out.println("2. Circle Check");
    System.out.println("3. Random Check");
    System.out.println("4. Exit");
    System.out.println("Please select an option>");
    menu_num=reader.nextInt();
    if(menu_num>4||menu_num<0)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
        
    }
    
    return menu_num;
}
public static int GoodBye(int GB)
{
    GB=0;
    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    return GB;
}

public static int Menu_0 (int a)
{
    int Ps;
    System.out.println("Please insert the photo size>");
    Ps=reader.nextInt();
    if(Ps<0||Ps>12)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Photo Input!");
        return a;   
    }
    System.out.println("Please insert the photo value>");
    String strPhoto;
    do {
    strPhoto = reader.nextLine();
     } while(strPhoto.length() == 0);
    if(strPhoto.length()!=Ps*Ps)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Photo Input!");
        return a;   
    }
    for(int i=0;i<Ps*Ps;i++)
    {
        if(strPhoto.charAt(i)<'0'||strPhoto.charAt(i)>'F')
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Photo Input!");
            return a;   
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Is your array defined inside case 0 scope ?

Comment: I tried to define the array inside case 0, then thought about making a function that makes the array, didn't help me either @SeyedMohammadAminAtyabi

Comment: Edit this post and add  your code so we can help better. Generally you should define your array outside of switch statement, so you can access in other cases.

Comment: @SeyedMohammadAminAtyabi but in case the user wants to change the array how he can change it if it's outside? and sry if the code looks like shit, I'm pretty new to coding.

Comment: You are doing some thing like how you declared and instance of Scanner class.

Comment: @SeyedMohammadAminAtyabi  I would really appreciate it if you could show an example.

Comment: Of course. Do user have to input each cell of array ?

Comment: @SeyedMohammadAminAtyabi my instruction is this. option 0: the user will enter the size of the 2d array(if he input 6 it will be 6*6), then the user input 36 values in the range 0-F.  then we need to make function that get this info and return char array.     option 1: this option will print the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment3 {
static Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int checker=1;
    int user_selction;
    char [][]array = null;
    
    do {
        user_selction=Menu();
        switch(user_selction) {
        case 0:
            array = Menu_0();
            break;
        case 1:
            print_array(array);
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        case 4:
            checker=GoodBye(checker);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        
    }while(checker==1);

}
public static int Menu ()
{
    int menu_num;
    System.out.println("~ Photo Analyzed ~");
    System.out.println("0. Load Photo");
    System.out.println("1. Print Photo");
    System.out.println("2. Circle Check");
    System.out.println("3. Random Check");
    System.out.println("4. Exit");
    System.out.println("Please select an option>");
    menu_num=reader.nextInt();
    if(menu_num>4||menu_num<0)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
        
    }
    
    return menu_num;
}
public static int GoodBye(int GB)
{
    GB=0;
    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    return GB;
}

public static char[][] Menu_0 ()
{
    int Ps;
    System.out.println("Please insert the photo size>");
    Ps=reader.nextInt();
    if(Ps<0||Ps>12)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Photo Input!");
        return null;   
    }
    System.out.println("Please insert the photo value>");

    char [][]array = new char[Ps][Ps];

    for(int i=0;i<Ps;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < Ps ; j++)
        {
            char c = reader.next().charAt(0);
            if(c<'0'||c>'F')
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid Photo Input!");
                return null;   
            } else {
                array[i][j] = c;
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}

public static void print_array(char [][]array){
    for (int i = 0 ; i < array[0].length ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < array[0].length ; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Wow Thk , i had to change some things because when i tried to print it didnt work, but the null helped alot . thk!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use Scanner like this:

```
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Select 1 to input array size or 2 to do sth");
            int option = sc.nextInt();


            switch(option) {    

            case 1 :
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter array size: ");
                int size = sc.nextInt()
                int[] array = new array[size*size];
                break;

            case 2 :
                something;
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("No such option ");
                break;
            }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).